# Apache, www-data and custom user permission

Tags: apache, wordpress, users

I'm running an ubuntu server with apache and I have web directory which is owned by the user www-data and the group www-data. WordPress works great in this directory. It can auto update and I can upload files.

I want to also create a web directory which is owned by another custom user I'm going to add. However when I change the owner on the web directory from www-data to the customer user WordPress is no longer to auto update and I can not upload unless I change the group permission.

Is there a way to make my custom user act like the apache www-data user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your customer in the same group as www-data and set your/their FTP config to always upload with group permissions set to be read/writeable by www-data.

What this might be a problem with is when you get another customer. You will not want customer A being able to read/write customer B's data.

Therefore consider doing it the other way, having Apache run with the customer's uid + gid. This can be done, more instructions on how to configure your vhosts etc is here:

http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/5/19/configuring-the-apache-mpm-on-ubuntu

Comment: Cool, I'll check this out over the weekend. I've been considering the 1st approach. Assigning the customer as the owner and www-data as a group and making the permissions 775 for folders and 6664 for files.